# Обновление данных потягиванием вниз

Tags: java, android, ui

Здравствуйте все.) Наверное, все знают приложение ВКонтакте. Все также знают, что там новости(и сообщения, и тд) обновляются по потягиванию вниз.. Внимание, вопрос: как же это сделать?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я не знал, зато видел как это у GMail и гугловских продуктах делается.
Сейчас почти все приложения такого типа вот так обновляют вид.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такое действие называется `pullToRefresh`, есть несколько реализаций, например `SwipeRefreshLayout` из `Support.v4` - официальный.